# How to add if-else statement within onClick event based on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I currently have a page that loads in 2 seperate lists of data as cards from two seperate URLs I have that are as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/videos
http://localhost:3000/manuals
```

So I have a div that loads up two seperate list components and displays them together.  I also have a "Create Card" button that opens a modal, and once the information needed is filled in and the submit button is clicked, the onClick of the button loads up the "CreateCard" function.

Originially, I had a working page that would create cards successfully but it would only submit it to /videos. I have now created 2 seperate functions, one that creates /videos and on that creates /modules. Furthermore, I have added radio buttons that allows the user to decide on whether they are creating a /module or /video card. The code for the creating form is as follows:

```
<Popup
            trigger={<button className="btn blue-outline"> Create a new card</button>}
            modal
            position="right center">
            <div>
              <div>
                <label>Title:</label>
                <input
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  className="input"
                  name="createCardTitle"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.title}></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>URL:</label>
                <input
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  className="input"
                  name="createCardURL"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ url: e.target.value });
                  }}></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                <input
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  className="input"
                  name="createCardThumbnail"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ thumbnail: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
              </div>
              <label className="radio">
                <input
                  id="videoCardRadio"
                  type="radio"
                  name="radio_group_1"
                  value="video"
                  checked={this.state.whichRadioSelected === "video"}
                  onChange={() => this.setState({ whichRadioSelected: "video" })}
                />
                <span>Video Card</span>
              </label>
              <label className="radio">
                <input
                  id="manualCardRadio"
                  type="radio"
                  name="radio_group_1"
                  value="manual"
                  checked={this.state.whichRadioSelected === "manual"}
                  onChange={() => this.setState({ whichRadioSelected: "manual" })}
                />
                <span>Manual Card</span>
              </label>
              <br></br>
              <button
                style={{
                  float: "left"
                }}
                onClick={() => this.createManualProduct(this.state.title, this.state.url, this.state.thumbnail)}
                className="btn blue-outline"
                id="confirmModalBtn">
                Create
              </button>
            </div>
          </Popup>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can implement an if-else statement that would be able to determine whether or not a "video" or "manual" radio button is selected, and depending on that, if "video" was selected, then the createVideoCard() function is run. And if "manual" is selected, then the createManualCard() function is run.

The code for the rest of the page is available below just incase it is needed for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpList from "../components/helpAdmin/help/HelpList";
import "../components/helpAdmin/help/HelpList";
import "../components/helpAdmin/help/ManualHelpList";
import "../components/helpAdmin/help/HelpCard";
import { Modal, Button, Tooltip, Icon, Tabs, Checkbox, Radio } from "components/ui";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";


import ManualHelpList from "../components/helpAdmin/help/ManualHelpList";

interface Props {}

interface State {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
  thumbnail: string;
  isEditProduct: boolean;
  isAddProduct: boolean;
  id: string;
  whichRadioSelected: string;
}
interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

export class HelpAdminView extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    title: "",
    thumbnail: "",
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {},
    isEditProduct: true,
    isAddProduct: true,
    whichRadioSelected: ""
  };
  componentDidMount() {}

  createVideoProduct(title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/`;

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  createManualProduct(title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/manuals/`;

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="box">
          <Popup
            trigger={<button className="btn blue-outline"> Create a new card</button>}
            modal
            position="right center">
            <div>
              <div>
                <label>Title:</label>
                <input
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  className="input"
                  name="createCardTitle"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.title}></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>URL:</label>
                <input
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  className="input"
                  name="createCardURL"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ url: e.target.value });
                  }}></input>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                <input
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  className="input"
                  name="createCardThumbnail"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ thumbnail: e.target.value });
                  }}
                  value={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
              </div>
              <label className="radio">
                <input
                  id="videoCardRadio"
                  type="radio"
                  name="radio_group_1"
                  value="video"
                  checked={this.state.whichRadioSelected === "video"}
                  onChange={() => this.setState({ whichRadioSelected: "video" })}
                />
                <span>Video Card</span>
              </label>
              <label className="radio">
                <input
                  id="manualCardRadio"
                  type="radio"
                  name="radio_group_1"
                  value="manual"
                  checked={this.state.whichRadioSelected === "manual"}
                  onChange={() => this.setState({ whichRadioSelected: "manual" })}
                />
                <span>Manual Card</span>
              </label>
              <br></br>
              <button
                style={{
                  float: "left"
                }}
                onClick={() => this.createManualProduct(this.state.title, this.state.url, this.state.thumbnail)}
                className="btn blue-outline"
                id="confirmModalBtn">
                Create
              </button>
            </div>
          </Popup>
          <div className="listDisplay">
            <HelpList />
            <ManualHelpList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
export default HelpAdminView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `createVideo` if `this.state.whichRadioSelected === "video"` if not call `createManuals` like this

```
clickHandler = () => {
    if(this.state.whichRadioSelected === "video") {
      this.createVideo();
    } else {
      this.createManuals();
    } 
}
```

and in your button, pass this handler function to your `onClick` event like this

```
<Button onClick={() => {this.clickHandler();}}
```

Comment: how would I go about putting this in my OnClick  function?